# Celsius to Fahrenheit in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I am new in programming and I would like to create a program like the one described in the photo.
[image]
In the file 'converter.component.html', I wrote this code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<fieldset>
  Celsius : <input type ="text"/ > Fahrenheit :{{celcius}} <span> </span>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

In the file 'converter.component.ts', I wrote this code.

```
function celsiusToFahrenheit($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('celsius', function(value) {
    $scope.fahrenheit = value * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
  });
}
```

But it does not work for me

Comment: Please, could you show how to do it

Comment: What do you mean when you say " it does not work for me " What happen et what is suppose to happen. Do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: @Nicolas My page does not convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit , but i wrote formula correctly

Comment: Saying "my page [that should do X] does not do X" is the same as "it does not work". What should happen, what is actually happening and why do you think it's not working? It displays a wrong calculation result? Shows nothing at all? Throws some error?

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos I cannot create such kind of program that given in requirement

Comment: Hey man just a suggestion, do not ask university exam and homework questions on stack overflow. It is not the place to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

converter.component.html

```
<!-- Add other tags by yourself))-->
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="convert()">
result {{result}}
```

converter.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    constructor() { }
  public value: number;
  public result: number;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  convert(){
    this.result = this.value * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
  }
}
```